# Pre-prepared column names for MySQL query not working

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms

I have this PHP file that is supposed to take all the information submited to it by a form, and place it in a MySQL database. Right now, I'm in the stage of making sure I have all the information, and I'm preparing a `"insert into (" . $var . ")"` type query.

**The array:**

```
$merged_arrays = array( 
    $sales_rep = strtoupper($_POST['sales_rep']),
    $c_first_name = strtoupper($_POST['c_first_name']),
    $c_last_name = strtoupper($_POST['c_last_name']),
    $c_address = strtoupper($_POST['c_address']),
    $c_zip = strtoupper($_POST['c_zip']),
    $deal_number = strtoupper($_POST['deal_number']),
    $deal_stock_number = strtoupper($_POST['deal_stock_number']),
    $deal_selling_model = strtoupper($_POST['deal_selling_model']),
    $deal_new_status = strtoupper($_POST['deal_new_status']),
    $deal_dh = strtoupper($_POST['deal_dh']),
    $deal_finance_amount = strtoupper($_POST['deal_finance_amount']),
    $deal_pack = strtoupper($_POST['deal_pack']),
    $deal_retro = strtoupper($_POST['deal_retro']),
    $deal_holdback = strtoupper($_POST['deal_holdback']),
    $sales_rep2 = strtoupper($_POST['sales_rep2']) or $sales_rep2 = null,
    $deal_trade_in_model_1 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_model_1']),
    $deal_trade_in_amount_1 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_amount_1']),
    $deal_trade_in_model_2 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_model_2']),
    $deal_trade_in_amount_2 = strtoupper($_POST['deal_trade_in_amount_2']),
    $deal_reserve_amount = strtoupper($_POST['deal_reserve_amount']),
    $deal_warrantee = strtoupper($_POST['deal_warrantee']),
    $deal_gap = strtoupper($_POST['deal_gap']),
    $deal_etch = strtoupper($_POST['deal_etch']),
    $deal_maintenence = strtoupper($_POST['deal_maintenence']),
    $deal_gross = strtoupper($_POST['deal_gross']));
```

**Supplemental Array**:
This is the array "dictionary" that stores all the translation of the php varibles to the literal column names in the table.

```
$column_dictionary = array(
    $sales_rep = "Sales Rep 1",
    $c_first_name = "Customer First Name",
    $c_last_name = "Customer Last Name",
    $c_address = "Street Address",
    $c_zip = "Zip",
    $c_city = "City",
    $c_state = "State",
    $deal_number = "Deal Number",
    $deal_stock_number = "Stock #",
    $deal_selling_model = "Model",
    $deal_new_status = "New/Used",
    $deal_dh = "Destination and Handling Amount",
    $deal_finance_amount = "Financing Amount",
    $deal_pack = "Pack Amount",
    $deal_retro = "Retro Amount",
    $deal_holdback = "Holdback Amount",
    $sales_rep2 = "Sales Rep 2",
    $deal_trade_in_model_1 = "Trade-In Vehicle 1 Description",
    $deal_trade_in_amount_1 = "Trade-In Vehicle 1 Amount",
    $deal_trade_in_model_2 = "Trade-in Vehicle 2 Description",
    $deal_trade_in_amount_2 = "Trade-in Vehicle 2 Amount",
    $deal_reserve_amount = "Reserve Amount",
    $deal_warrantee = "Warrantee Amount",
    $deal_gap = "Gap Amount",
    $deal_etch = "Etch Amount",
    $deal_maintenence = "Maintenance Amount",
    $deal_gross = "Gross Amount");
```

**The While loop:**
The loop evaluates the array `$merged_arrays` to see if there's any content. If there is content, it's expected to put it in a varible, `$columms`.

```
$columns = "";
$i = 0;
while($i < 26) {
    if (!$merged_arrays[$i] == false) {
        $columns = $columns . "`" . $column_dictionary[$i] . "`, ";
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

**The problem:**
When I run this, with the form submitted with the values, `$deal_trade_in_model_2` keeps showing up (along with it's brother, `$deal_trade_in_amount_2`) in the column variable, reguardless of if theres input in the form or not. `$deal_maintenence` as well as `$deal_gross` is never listed, even though I run a javsacript function to make sure that they're all set to "$0" (because its a currency field. I've tried pretty much everything I can think of for the last couple of hours, and I really need to learn what I'm doing wrong so I don't keep making the same mistake.

I've attached a JS Fiddle of the page with the form it's sending it to, as well as all the JS and CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/23smyy8g/

When answering this question, please take on the role of a teacher. I like learning from my mistakes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named arrays use the arrow notation.

```
$myArray = array(
     'sales_rep' => 'Sales rep name',
     'company' => 'Company Name'
);
```

### Edit

You can use a foreach loop to avoid handleling the increment step. Also it looks like your if statement is causing the problem.

```
if (!$merged_arrays[$i] == false)
```

The `!` not operator has higher precedence than the `==` comparison, so this nots the column, and checks if that is false, which is most likely not what you are trying. I'm assuming you wish to check that it is not null/falsey, the empty function can be used for this. If you just want to check that it is not false, use the `!=` operator like so:

```
if ($merged_arrays[$i] != false)
```

Also note that `.=` is more concise vs `$str = $str . 'extra'`.

```
$columns = "";
foreach ($merged_arrays  as $key => $column)
    if (!empty($column)) {
        $columns .= "`" . $column_dictionary[$key] . "`, ";
    }
}
```

### Further Edit

You should construct your arrays in the following manner:

```
array(
    'key1' => value1,
    'key2' => value2
)
```

Your arrays are actually holding the result of a variable assignment.

Comment: Noted. But why would it not work for only four of the items in the array?

Comment: Does the POST variable contain all 26 values?

Comment: Yes. I've verified that.

Comment: Then the problem is most likely in your while loop. I will edit my answer in a minute.